# NOOBS preloaded SD Cards and OSMC

Tags: sd-card, noobs, osmc

I bought a CANA RPi2 starter kit that came with a microSD card preloaded with NOOBS and some OSs to use. It did not, however, come with OSMC and that's what I want to use on my RPi2.

Should I reformat the SD card before I put OSMC on there per the directions on OSMC website? Or can I just add it to the SD card as is?

Comment: I didn't end up reformatting and just put OSMC on preloaded SD Card. When I turned on RPi2, it automatically started installing OSMC and didn't bring up NOOBS menu at all. So I guess I don't need to reformat.

Answer (score 1):

Well. If it's not there, you can simply reflash your SD card. Do the following.

The flashing process can be easily achieved through **NOOBS**, which you can download [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/).

As taken from the docs, to flash the drive:

> To set up a blank SD card with NOOBS:
>
> 1. Format an SD card that is 4GB or larger as FAT. See instructions on
>      how to do this below.
> 2. Download and extract the files from the NOOBS zip file.
> 3. Copy the extracted files onto the SD card that you just
>      formatted so that this file is at the root directory of the SD card.
>      Please note that in some cases it may extract the files into a folder;
>      if this is the case then please copy across the files from inside the
>      folder rather than the folder itself.
> 4. On first boot the "RECOVERY" FAT partition will be automatically resized to a minimum, and a list of OS's that are available to install will be displayed.

For more information on that process, you can check this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md).

After that, you'll be able to install and use the XBMC distribution. First, boot your Pi with **NOOBs**, then on the selection screen, chose either **OpenELEC** or **OSMC** and then press `Install`. After that the wizard will prompt you to confirm, press `Yes`. Now you'll just have to wait until you see a message like this:

> OS(es) Installed Successfully

Now click on `OK` and your Pi will reboot on XBMC. Pretty straight forward.

This tutorial was taken from this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/xbmc/). You can check it for more information on how to use XBMC, and how to mount network drives such as a NAS.

Answer (score 0):

please follow the "tutorial" on the [OSMC website](https://osmc.tv/download/)!

you can return to use NOOBS every time by [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/) of the very good [Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/).

---

***optional:*** you can also follow [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md) to copy any [image](https://osmc.tv/download/images/) direct to your SD card.